# Toggle uppercase and lowercase python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-requests

how do I make the program ask for a name and then alternate the result in uppercase and lowercase?

Example:

How is your name?
george

Hello GeOrGe

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Alternate Cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973151/python-alternate-cases)

Answer (score 1):

```
print("How is your name?");
name = input();
list(name)
letters = list(name)
final_word = ""
for x in range(len(name)):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        final_word += letters[x].upper()
    else:
        final_word += letters[x].lower()
else:
    print("Hello" + final_word)
```

I think this code should work

Answer (score 1):

you can use `list comprehension` -

```
s =  input()
s  = ''.join(item.upper() if index%2 ==0  else item.lower() for index,item in enumerate(s))
```